# scipy.optimize.minimize throwing error

Tags: qiskit, quantum-circuit, optimization

I used `minimize` for optimizing the ansatz parameter. I wrote the line like
`result = minimize(cost, init_params, method="COBYLA", options={'maxiter':200})`
and it is throwing this error `ValueError: Mismatching number of values and parameters. For partial binding please pass a dictionary of {parameter: value} pairs.`. Although I'm sure this is how `maxiter` is given and shown in Qiskit notebooks.
For further information, this is my circuit
[image: circuit]

and I'm sure `init_params` have been given 9 initial parameters for each $R_y$ gates in the ansatz. So I'm wondering where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you've created this circuit, it has either 0 or 1 parameter at most. 0 if you just perform a rotation of angle $1$, and 1 if you've created your gates using a parameter named `"1"`. Create your circuit like this and it should work:

```python
from qiskit.circuit import QuantumCircuit, Parameter

qc = QuantumCircuit(3, 3)

for i in range(3):
    qc.ry(Parameter(f"$\\theta_{i}$"), i)

qc.cz(0, 1)
qc.cz(0, 2)

for i in range(3):
    qc.ry(Parameter(f"$\\theta_{i + 3}$"), i)

qc.cz(1, 2)
qc.cz(0, 2)

for i in range(3):
    qc.ry(Parameter(f"$\\theta_{i + 6}$"), i)

qc.draw("mpl")
```

This will give you the following result:
[image: Circuit drawing]
As a side note, you can check the number of parameters your circuit expects using the `num_parameters` attribute:

```python
print(qc.num_parameters) # Should print 9
```

Comment: I assigned parameters like this ```for i in range(len(qubits)):
    ansatz.ry(params[0][i], qubit=qubits[i])```. 1 is the value of theta or at least what I intend to assign. params is 3 x 3 matrix of 1s and qubits = [0, 1, 2]. I repeated this three times.

Comment: It seems you're right. It has no parameters. How do I assign numeric values to the gate parameters?

Comment: That worked!! But I had to remove the classical registers for the optimization to work. But I'll need classical registers for analyzing the circuit so how can I add to an existing quantum circuit?

Comment: @Vaishnav Once the optimisation is over, it will also give you the set of parameters using which it reached the minimal value. You can then use the `bind_parameters` method of your quantum circuit to create a new quantum circuit with the right values for the parameters.